# Mapping a multilingual ElasticSearch document to a unilingual object using Nest Client

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am designing an application which uses the following objects

```
public class Entity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

The objects according to a language parameter are populated from Searching ElasticSearch documents (Nest .NET Client) like the following

```
{ 
  "Title": {
     "en": "...",
     "fr": "..."
  },
  "Description": {
     "en": "...",
     "fr": "..."
  }
}
```

I am trying to find out how using a language parameter I can map the proper document field to the object property using the Nest .NET Client.

For example if language is en I want the en Title and Description values to populate the object.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Object Initilizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/source-filtering-usage.html#_object_initializer_syntax_example_18) syntax
and conditionally create your query

```
var searchReq=new SearchRequest<Entity>
{
    Query = EntityFilter, --> create your query query
    Source = new SourceFilter
    {
        Includes = ["Title.en","Description.en"]
    }
}
```